# Is there a sublime text color theme that is just 2 colors? (black on grey)

Tags: sublime-text

I prefer coding without any text highlighting, namely black courier on light grey. Is there a Sublime Text color theme as specified? Perhaps one where it is easy to configure the background and foreground for all languages in a unified way?

Comment: Haven't seen one, but I'm sure you could easily do one yourself: http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/PlasticCodeWrap

Answer (score 0):

You may try "3024 Dark" color scheme. You can download it or check it from here: 
https://github.com/idleberg/3024.tmTheme
 Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

I also haven't seen a two color package for Sublime. You may find this short article ["Syntax Highlighting Off"](https://www.robertmelton.com/2016/02/24/syntax-highlighting-off/) useful. It was trending on the front page of hacker news, for whatever that's worth. The blog post shows images of this user's two color syntax theme, which he created & uses in his text editor (images in post) to code with just two colors. Using the tool @Altoid Muncher described, you can create a theme for Sublime.

**Edit**: The nofrils dark theme for vim (shown above) has been ported to Atom and can be found [here](https://atom.io/themes/nothrill-dark-syntax)

[image: Two color syntax theme]